Adding Thread.sleep in spring boot web app adding delays to subsequent requests
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greet() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        return "<h1>Hello from Spring boot app<h1>";
    }
}

In a browser open 2 tabs. Send first request in one tab and immediately in second tab seond other request. The first request is served in 4 seconds, however 2nd request is taking around 7 seconds. Why is this? Servlet container is thread per request right, then if each request is spawned innew thread each request should ideally be served in 4 seconds only. Can anyone explain what's happening here.

Which servlet container are you using? Show us your boot config. Provide a [mcve].

Browsers have limits on how many requests go to 1 URL concurrently as well, it is not only the server that plays a role.

Its just a starter spring boot application, no other code than this controller. So by default it is using the tomcat container.

Considering "Browsers have limits on how many requests go to 1 URL concurrently as well", i tried sending the request from different browser, one from edge and one from chrome, now i can see that both are served in 4 seconds. Is there any settings in the browser where we can set max concurrent req to same server ?

Why are adding a sleep to your code? Are you trying to simulate something? Provide context.

Are your requests served synchronously?

Browser limitations play a role here, when you open two tabs and send requests to the same endpoint, the browser is probably sending the first request then waiting for it to complete, and then sending the second request.
